# D3.js or Sigmajs is more good for network visualisation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, sigma.js

Iam trying to build network visualisation graphs.I want to have search for nodes,callbacks for nodes click and actions,visually appealing,simpler and lighter and faster interface.
Also it should scale up.
I tried googling anf figured out d3.js and sigma js.
Which one is more good for my usecase ?

Comment: opinion based question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

D3.js:

- won't scale up to more than a couple of hundreds of nodes/edges (SVG only)
- easy to use and customize if you aleasy know D3

Sigma.js:

- scales up to thousands of nodes/edges (using Canvas or WebGL renderers)
- easy to use and customize
- easy node/edge interactions
- lots of cool existing plugins

I strongly believe (and contributed to) a fork of Sigma.js called [Linkurious.js](https://github.com/Linkurious/linkurious.js). It fixes lots of issues and adds lots of cool plugins that make building network visualizations really easy.

Comment: i understood that  Linkurious.js is a great tool for graph visualisation.Bu what about the community support for the same ?

Comment: Can you tell me is it possible to change color of a link/node dynamically  based on the flag set by an ajax call ?

Comment: Linkurious.js is open source and free for non-commercial projects. This means that you get all the features for free if your project is non-commercial. Regarding styling nodes/edge, please refer to the wiki: https://github.com/Linkurious/linkurious.js/wiki/Styling